# Sitecore 8.1- Language preformance issue

Tags: sitecore, sitecore8.1

While changing the language of an item, it is taking around 4-6 seconds for the choosen language to get reflected, that too for admin users. For non-admin, it is taking more than 8seconds which is causing a major performance issue. Kindly let me know how this issue can be resolved or atleast performance enhanced.

Comment: Does performance improve if you turn off "Standard Fields" from the views tab? Do you have language fallback enabled? Or any custom field types?

Comment: No, it remains unaffected by unchecking "Standard fields". No we dont have language fallback enabled or any other custom fields types.

Comment: Check your infrastructure I worked on many Sitecore 8.1 solutions but I didn't have such a problem.

Comment: Are you using any list fields in your items like multilist, treelist, etc where you have to specify a query or source? If yes, tuning these queries will help.

Answer (score 0):

It would be worth you looking at the [CMS Performance Tuning Guide](https://sdn.sitecore.net/reference/sitecore%207/cms%20performance%20tuning%20guide.aspx) and the [CMS Diagnostics Guide](https://sdn.sitecore.net/Reference/Sitecore%207/CMS%20Diagnostics%20Guide.aspx) they are for 7.x but I do not believe there are version 8.x equivalents at the moment and most of the advice will still be valid.

Also check the Fragmentation level of indexes on your master database and have a SQL maintenance plan in place to rebuild these as often as your environment requires it can really help performance.

Check the Sitecore Logs for errors during the slow periods and monitor all servers in your environment to see where the performance bottle neck is, CPU, memory etc..

Comment: If I try to implement the above scenario directly from server, then it works absolutely fine for non admin users also without any time lag but from my local, if i do the same thing, it takes a lot time.

Comment: Have you tried looking in the Network tab of your browser developer tools to see what is taking a long time?

Comment: Yes it it sitecore.js file that is taking a lot time to load.The CM instance works fine when opened from the server, the js also takes less time to load but from the loca, it takes a lot time.

Comment: If the documentation mentioned in my answer does not point you in the right direction for diagnosing your performance issue I suggest contacting Sitecore support so they can assist you with it.